# Emoji break nano cursor

Tags: macos, zsh, emoji, nano

I am using iTerm2 and zsh on Mac. When I paste an emoji into nano, or scroll my cursor over one, the cursor changes to permanently be on top of the last character, rather than one space afterwards. This persists until I close zsh. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: This is an issue with using any proportionally spaced font in a terminal designed for monospaced fonts.

Comment: Is there way to resolve this then? I notice iTerm has an option for using a different font for non-ASCII text. Would this fix it? And what font could I use?

Comment: The "Use Unicode version 9 widths" setting might help, although I didn't bother to test.